# How can add action with QWidget.addAction()?

Tags: qt

In Qt, I want to add some actions in a widget using `QWidget.addAction()`.
I can easily do it with `QToolBar.addAction()`, but when I use `QWidget.addAction()`, it doesn't work.

How can I use `QWidget.addAction()`?

Here is my function:

```
void Reb::addActionToBar(QString *tabName, QAction *action)
{
    //if tab exist, just add the action, else:

    tab_widget->addTab(new QWidget(), *tabName);
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= tab_widget->count() ; i++) {
        if(tab_widget->tabText(i) == tabName) {
            action.setParent(tab_widget->widget(i));
            tab_widget->widget(i)->addAction(action);
        }
    }
}
```

And as you know tab_widget is a QTabWidget...
I have no error but i can't see my action in tab.

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried and the error you receive?

Comment: I inserted part of my code, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QWidget::addAction()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#addAction) does not do add the action to the UI - the only place where the widget's actions are shown is in the widget's context menu, given the right context menu policy.

QTabWidget has no means to display actions in its UI. Actions are usually displayed in toolbars or menubars, so you would need to add the action there.

As a side note, there is no need to pass QStrings by pointer, simply pass the QString by const reference:

```
 void Reb::addActionToBar(const QString &tabName, QAction *action)
```

Also, your code has an off-by-one error, use `i < tab_widget->count()` instead of `i <= tab_widget->count()` to fix that.